# Sending data form from JavaScript to PHP, manipulate it, and sending it back to JavaScript with Fetch

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, http, fetch

This is my JS code:

```
 let report_button = document.getElementById("report_button");

 report_button.addEventListener("click", e => {
 e.preventDefault();

let form = new FormData(document.getElementById("form"));

fetch("test.php", {
  method: "POST",
  body: form
}).then(res => {
  fetch("test.php", { method: "GET" })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => console.log(data));
});
});
```

and test.php:

```
<?php echo json_encode($_POST); ?>
```

But as response I am getting an empty array.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: In your second request, you're not passing any data so there's nothing for it to output. Every ajax request is a brand new request. There's also no reason to make the second request at all. Just use the result from the first request. That will contain the data you post to it.

Comment: `echo  file_get_contents('php://input');`

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
fetch("test.php", {
  method: "POST",
  body: form
}).then(res => {
  return res.json();
}).then(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the reponse data from the post, then you don't need the nested fetch with the GET. Instead just read the post response:

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        title: 'test 1',
        body: 'test 1',
        userId: 999
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      console.log('response: ' + JSON.stringify(json));
    });
```